# Why does landing gear extend backwards and retract forwards?

Tags: landing-gear

As you can see in the below image the front landing gear is retracting forwards, meaning that it extends forwards. What is the reason why they are made to drop backwards instead of forwards?

[image]
[Image Source](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Qantas/Airbus-A380-842/2788797/L/&sid=5d45b4f56c689507c38c7ad60fd13eb1)

Comment: It doesn't always, but this is often done so that the air helps to push the gear down (back).  This is useful in situations where the normal means of extension fail.

Comment: @fooot Thanks, I had a feeling that the question was already asked somewhere here but I could not find it.

Comment: There are quite a number of retractables where the main gear retracts inwards, towards the fuselage.  I don't have specific numbers, but I think it's the most common pattern on light planes, at least.

Comment: @jamesqf I know about that. The main gear on the plane in this image had that too. I am just asking about why backwards and not forwards for the gear that does that.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann: Then perhaps you should re-word your title & question to make it specific to nose gear?